# Restart Remote SQL SERVER Engine Using DBAtools

Tags: sql-server, dbatools

I have installed dbatools on a central server to remotely manage SQL servers. All the servers are part of a workgroup. I need to be able to remotely restart the SQL Server service whenever it's required.

I attempted to use the following PowerShell script:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "1234567" -AsPlainText -Force

$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("Administrator", $password)

Restart-DbaService -ComputerName 192.168.1.10 -Type Engine -Force -Credential $Cred
```

However, when I tried to execute this script, it resulted in an error message as follows:
[image]

Comment: `-ComputerName 192.168.1.10` is not the name of the machine. Use the fully qualified domain name. And ensure WinRM is set up correctly.